# Jenkins Groovy Script to Add Newly Created Build Package Files to GitHub

Tags: .net, jenkins, groovy, msbuild

I have below groovy in Jenkin to run a build and create "bin\Package". Jenkin and GIT servers are different.

```
 node {
    stage('Checkout') { git 'https://github.com/XXXX'}
    stage('Build') { bat ( "\"${tool 'MsBuild_Local'}\" /p:DeployOnBuild=true;Configuration=Release;OutputPath=bin\\Package") }



    stage('Deploy')
    {
               println "Entered"
    }
    }
```

Now I need to push this new "Package" folder to the same checkout GIT repository, from Jenkins server. But not sure which command I need to check here.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to reconsider if you really want to do that, like [this answer advises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27594747/6090676).

if you must:

- if you're not using pipeline, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19922435/6090676).
- if you are using pipeline, see [this documented example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/push-git-repo/pushGitRepo.Groovy).

Comment: I am using pipeline and so tried 2nd option to get a message saying  "No such DSL method 'usernamePassword"

Comment: I am seeing credential plugin has been enabled and still same message. More over is it good to just to mention uid/pwd etc..through withCredentialsnkins ? Again I am pretty new in Jenkin/Groovy.

Comment: it's fine to use withCredentials from a security perspective. that's sort of what it's for. note that you can also use ssh keys instead of user/password. you might repost your Jenkinsfile with the failing `withCredentials` included in case someone can spot the issue.

Comment: I skipped the GIT idea and now trying to push deployment to an Azure storage account. Once adding my Azure storage account in Jenkin configuration, it's throwing error by telling "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target XXX.....Any idea?

Comment: it's generally better to submit a question for each distinct issue after researching it to make sure you can't solve it yourself. it seems like https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message could be related to this new issue. if there is a correct answer to the original question, you can accept it. :)